# Notification crashes application

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to pass `NSMutableDictionary` to `NSNotification` to other class.
But when releasing `NSMutableDictionary` application crashes.
can any one help?
I am trying this

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
temp =  [responseString JSONValue];
NSLog(@"webdata is %@",temp);
NSLog(@"inside usersignup success");
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CNotifySignupSucess object:temp];
[temp release];
```

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(signupsucessreceived:) name:CNotifySignupSucess object:nil];

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *dict = notification.object;
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"Success"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
       
      appDelegate.islogin=TRUE;
    self.title=nil;
    [appDelegate.userinfo setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"userid"];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *strtemp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"user_id"]];
        [defaults setObject:strtemp forKey:@"userid"];

Comment: crash only shows objc release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to read some iOS programming basics. And,

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
temp =  [responseString JSONValue]; //----> this line is wrong
```

because, `temp` pointer points to the newly created `NSMutableDictionary` object, the you are reassigning it to another object returned by `JSONValue` method, which is `autorelease` object, and you don't own it, thus can't `release` it. Some better ways to achieve want you want would be:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary *temp =  [responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"webdata is %@",temp);
    NSLog(@"inside usersignup success");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CNotifySignupSucess object:temp];
    //NO RELEASING the AUTORELEASE OBJECT!!!!
```

OR:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[responseString JSONValue]];
    NSLog(@"webdata is %@",temp);
    NSLog(@"inside usersignup success");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CNotifySignupSucess object:temp];
    [temp release];
```

OR:

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [temp addEntriesFromDictionary:[responseString JSONValue]];
    NSLog(@"webdata is %@",temp);
    NSLog(@"inside usersignup success");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CNotifySignupSucess object:temp];
    [temp release];
```

In the last 2 cases I'm considering that `JSONValue` method returns `NSDictionary`. Goog Luck!